# Obtain prices at various intervals after a trade

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following ticks containing bid and ask prices

```
                             Bid      Ask
Date                                     
2020-12-01 01:01:00.119  1777.68  1778.06
2020-12-01 01:01:00.316  1777.75  1778.16
2020-12-01 01:01:01.917  1777.77  1778.16
2020-12-01 01:01:04.523  1777.83  1778.21
2020-12-01 01:01:06.529  1777.87  1778.26
```

and another dataframe containing trades

```
                     Type  Volume    Price
Date                                      
2020-12-01 02:06:46   buy    0.01  1779.35
2020-12-01 02:07:19  sell    0.01  1778.75
2020-12-01 05:10:17   buy   10.00  1783.42
2020-12-01 05:36:41  sell   10.00  1785.30
2020-12-01 06:14:21   buy   10.00  1785.89
```

I am trying to obtain the bid or ask price at the following times:

- From ticks 0 to 5, the price before the trade and the 5 following ticks
- Also the price at various times after the trade: say 30 seconds, 1 minute and 5 minutes

I have been able to obtain the price before and after the trade comes in individually using for loops but I have not idea how to get the prices for multiple ticks and various times all at the same time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.